# Does Java have Identical Comparison Operator example ===

Tags: java

Java is a Strong Static Casting so does that mean there is no use for "==="

I have looked at tons of documentation and have not seen Identical Comparison Operator.

Comment: (Java does not allow `int == String` so there is little need of a `===` as found in languages like JavaScript.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`===` is useful in weak typed languages, such as Javascript, because it verifies that the objects being compared are of the same type and avoids implicit conversions.

`===` has absolutely no use in a strongly typed language such as Java because you can't compare variables of different types without writing a specific method for doing this.

---

For example, if you want to compare an `int` to a `String` in `Java`, you will have to write some special method as such:

```
boolean compareIntString(int i, String s) {
    return (i == parseInt(s));
}
```

But this is pretty much overkill.  (And as you'll notice, as written, this method only accepts an `int` and a `String`.  It doesn't accept just any two variables.  You know before you call it that the datatypes are different.)

The main point is, that while you can do `i == s` in `Javascript`, you can't do `i == s` in `Java`, so you don't need `===`.

---

I guess, the short answer is that `Java`'s `==` is `Javascript`'s `===`.  If you want to emulate `Javascript`'s `==` and compare two items, ignoring data type, you'll have to write a custom method which accepts generic data types as arguments... and figure out the logic on comparing, at a minimum, all the possible combinations of `Java`'s primitive data types...

Comment: Ya, that's what I was thinking, I was reading documentation and wanted to be sure.

Comment: Please don't use the terms “strong typing” or “weak typing”, as both are ill-defined. A weak type system may be one that allows arbitrary casts (such as C), dynamic typing, implicit coercions (which Java also has – consider primitive types), or simply a type system which I personally find inelegant (the most common meaning), depending on who you ask. Regarding coercions in Java: numeric types get automatically promoted to wider types, and you can compare floating point values with integral types without explicit coercions. Furthermore, the `+` may coerce arguments to strings.

Answer (score 6):

No java does not have `===` operator. Reason is pretty well explained by *nhgrif*. Here is the list of operators in java and their precedence:

[image]

**Source**: **http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html**

Comment: @PM77-1 The image is used to show all the legal operators in java. Tweaking was not required.

Comment: I tend to agree with @PM77-1 HOWEVER... the question did state that he had looked through documentation and couldn't find an answer.  This answer does provide the documentation that the question-asker should have looked at.